# Can you run multiple clr instances on a windows server?

Tags: java, asp.net, jvm, clr

I hear that on the other side, Java folks run multiple jvm instances on their servers and load balance not just the servers but also instances. How is this possible in asp.net? pools?

Answer (score 4):

If you are referring to ASP.NET on IIS, then yes, each application pool can have its own version of the CLR, because they are individual processes.  This doesn't particularly help for load balancing however- IIS takes care of that on it's own.  I'm pretty sure you'd just be hampering it.